# how to delete dynamically allocated parameter

Tags: c++, object

I'am creating a game and I'am struggled at this point:

in the .h file I have:

```
std::vector<int*> m_Vector;
```

then in the .cpp file:

```
 m_Vector.push_back(new Object1(new Object2()));
```

I know I can delete Object1 this way:

```
 delete m_Vector[0]
```

but how can I delete Object2?
Thanks!

Comment: Storing `Object1` pointers as `int` pointers is going to cause you lots of problems...

Comment: What did you try, where did you fail in particular?

Comment: Why the pointers in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Object1` has a `Object2 *obj2` member, and that this is set in `Object1`'s constructor, you would need to do the following:

```
delete m_Vector[0].obj2;
delete m_Vector[0];
```

However, since you're using C++, you should probably use [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t4fe76c.aspx).

Also, why are you storing `Object1*`s in a `std::vector<int*>`?

Comment: Ok I got it std::vector<Object*> but Object2 obj2 is not a member of Object1 it's a parameter passed to a base class, and delete m_Vector[0].obj2; did not work

Comment: @user3885884 `delete m_Vector[0].obj2;` very well may not work. I did state in my answer that I am assuming that the name of the `Object2` member is `obj2`. Don't just blindly copy my code into your project. Please make the appropriate replacements first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using new Object2() as a parameter for the new Object1 constructor. If that is the case, then the second object is not stored in the vector at all. Secondly, the vector only holds int* type objects (or integer pointers). I am not entirely clear on why you need a new class with a custom constructor to add an int* to your vector. I would highly recommend taking a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ for information about the vector class.

Comment: Actually, it's std::vector<Object*> m_Vector and yes you're right new Object2() is a parameter not a member

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should store pointers to `Object1` and not `int`.

On the other hand you can get rid of all the problems with releasing the allocated memory if you used smart pointers.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object1>> m_Vector;
```

and then create objects like this:

```
m_Vector.push_back(std::make_shared<Object1>());
```

In turn, `Object1` should also use a `std::shared_ptr`, etc.

Note that if you do not need to share the objects you should use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: why even use a shared pointer? If there's no need to do otherwise, just store the object by value